# PostgreSQL UTC to CET/CEST

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I have some big trouble with timezones and Benjamin Franklin.

I have a table with an UTC timestamp field, no timezone is stored.

My goal is to group the rows of this table by day of week or by slices like n hours.

This id how I proceeded until now :

```
-- CET  => UTC/GMT + 1 => Winter
-- CEST => UTC/GMT + 2 => Summer
--
-- Hour changes 2014 : march 30th, 2h CET => 3h CEST
--
--
--      Output for "d"             Wanted output for "d"
-- "2014-03-28 23:00:00+00"   "2014-03-28 23:00:00+00" (23h UTC because CET)
-- "2014-03-29 23:00:00+00"   "2014-03-29 23:00:00+00" (23h UTC because CET)
-- "2014-03-30 23:00:00+00"   "2014-03-30 22:00:00+00" (22h UTC because CEST : fail because start timestamp is CET)

SELECT dates.d AS d, archives_d, range_begin_date, sequentialid

  FROM generate_series('2014-03-28T23:00:00+00:00'::timestamp, -- 23h UTC because CET -- 2014-03-28T22:00:00+00:00
                       '2014-03-31T21:59:59+00:00'::timestamp, -- 22h UTC because CEST -- 2014-03-31T21:59:59+00:00
                       '86400 seconds') AS dates(d)

  LEFT JOIN (
     -- Select archive date floored by a step (here 86400 seconds -> 24 hours)
     SELECT *, (to_timestamp(((floor(extract(epoch from (archives.range_begin_date - '2014-03-28T23:00:00+00:00'::timestamp)) / 86400)) * 86400) + extract(epoch from '2014-03-28T23:00:00+00:00'::timestamp))) AS archives_d
     FROM archives
  ) AS archives
    ON dates.d = archives.archives_d

 ORDER BY dates.d
```

Do you have any idea of how get the wanted output (at least for the generate series).

Note that my step for the generate series is not fixed at one day but an arbitrary interval.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for Benjamin Franklin

Comment: A self-contained example would be nice - what's the `archives` table referenced here? Have you looked at the `AT TIME ZONE` operator?

Comment: Why do you provide hours time explicitly as GMT instead of local time or desired timezone?

Comment: Why do you want to manually calculate time-zone differences? What is wrong with postgresql's `timestamptz` and `AT TIME ZONE`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT

Comment: The problem is i have no choice for the content of the table, it's UTC and I cannot change it. The timestamp is the time at the archive creation (here an archive references many receipts for a restaurant), the datetime is NOW() in UTC when the archive is created, and I can have many archives for one day.

Comment: Yes I looked for AT TIME ZONE but the problem is the same, I have to manually specify CET or CEST.

Comment: Ok I just figured that 'Europe/Paris' automatically select CET or CEST ... So I use it but I must return UTC at the end and AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' doesn't work (that's make sense), I go search how to do. Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a complete list of timezone names and offsets in [pg_timezone_names](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html).

I'm guessing you want a city-based name rather than a zone-based name. That way you get daylight-saving adjustments thrown in.

```
=> SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS ny, now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' AS lon;
            ny             |            lon
---------------------------+---------------------------
 2014-08-04 09:01:06.08988 | 2014-08-04 14:01:06.08988
(1 row)
```

The above was posted at 13:01 UTC. I'm guessing New York is what you want, but geography isn't my strong point :-)